# Nanoframework ESP32 OneWire Pin

Tags: nanoframework

is the one wire bus for ESP32 only available for pin 16 and 17? I am going to rework a project which was first written in Arduino IDE. There it was possible to set the pin for the one wire bus. I want to use nanoframework but my pcb is already there and port 15 and 23 are used for the one wire bus. I really like nanoframework and the sample for DS18B20 does not find any sensor. With Arduino IDE it is working. Is there a way to specifiy the pin for one wire? THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET nanoFramework implements support for 1-Wire protocol using UART, therefore it requires both TX and RX UART pins to work. On the pre-build firmware images it's configured to use pins 16 and 17 as you've mentioned.

You have to connect those together and also add a 4.7k pull up resistor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... In my case it is bad, because I already have my PCB running. Is it planned to support OnWire with a specified Pin? In my case I have 18 DS18B20 sensors running on 2 OneWire Pins...